# Multiple JSON files from a CSV

Tags: json, powershell

I have a script that reads each row of a csv file and add everything in a PsCustomObject. It can create a json file named **"Kevin Jessica.json"** with all values.

```
{
    "MyClass":  [
                    {
                        "Name":  "Kevin",
                        "Language":  "Powershell",
                        "State":  "Texas"
                    }
                ]
}
{
    "MyClass":  [
                    {
                        "Name":  "Jessica",
                        "Language":  "C",
                        "State":  "NewYork"
                    }
                ]
}
```

However, I want to create a separate json file for each person instead.

*whatever3.csv:*

```
Name,Language,State
Kevin,Powershell,Texas
Jessica,C,NewYork
```

*My current script:*

```
$csvData   = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\user1\Downloads\whatever3.csv"
$fileNames = $csvData.Name | Select -Unique
$DestinationDir = "C:\Users\user1\Downloads\sample"
$customheader = "MyClass"

$all = $csvData | ForEach-Object {
    $val = $_ | Select-Object *
[PsCustomObject]@{
$customheader = @($val)
} | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "$DestinationDir\$fileNames.json"
}
```

**Desired output:**

*Kevin.json*

```
{
    "MyClass":  [
        {
            "Name":  "Kevin",
            "Language":  "Powershell",
            "State":  "Texas"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Jessica.json*

```
{
    "MyClass":  [
        {
            "Name":  "Jessica",
            "Language":  "C",
            "State":  "NewYork"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Add-Content` to `Set-Content` and use the value of the `.Name` property of each object to create the destination paths:

```
Import-Csv path\tocsv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $path = Join-Path $DestinationDir -ChildPath ($_.Name + '.json')
    @{ $customheader = @($_) } | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $path
}
```